# Composite database in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I have a database, `financials` that has models created in django. In addition, it has other tables that were created for a python script that uses `MySQLdb`, and thus not in django. The python script needs the django tables  to work. In addition, the django tables needs to use the tables created outside of django to work.

How would I import these tables to use in django, or do I need to re-write them in django? In addition, it is potentially 'un-safe' to have a database that combines django and non-django tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't care what created your tables, and there are no issues with running them side-by-side. If you need access to the "non-Django" tables via the Django ORM, you could run `inspectdb` as described in the documentation on [using legacy databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/legacy-databases/).